# html-php form submission after validation through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dom-events

What I intend to do is : first validate a form and then process if some conditions are satisfied. I have pasted the prototype of my code below.
I have cross checked for any minor/silly errors.

Code:

```
<form id = "myform" action = process.php method = 'post'>
//some form elements here
<input type="submit" value="Submit this form"onclick="validate();return false;" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
if(validated) myform.submit();
else Alert(Some message); 
</script>
}
```

Comment: I can see three outright errors, several instances of bad style, but no actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to do something like this:

```
<form id="myform" action="process.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
//some form elements here
<input type="submit" value="Submit this form" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    ...
    if(!valid)
        alert('Error');
    return valid;
}
</script>
```